# How can I use Jquery to load different pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, onclick, show

I want to load a page by default but give options to go to 2 other pages.  Using JQuery, what can I use to have one page load by default and then when the user clicks on the other page options the content loads in the same div container rather than another page.  I've seen this been done before but not sure how to go about it?

Do I use jquery show hide?

Comment: That would be ajax, and jQuery's [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method is probably the easiest to start with.

Comment: @KyleNeedham Erm, no it wasn't http://api.jquery.com/load/ and `.on` is use as handler for DOM events, not ajax requests